# Specific use of Qtip that I cannot figure out how to implement

Tags: jquery, menu, position, fixed, qtip

I am trying to use the qtip plugin from jquery to make a sort of menu -except I don't need to use it to navigate, I just want it to be a visual aid to my current setup:
(link)
http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/cs195/final/S/S.html

right now I have the qtips so they are all working, but now I want to position them so they will all line up at the bottom of the outer-most television.

Is it possible to fix the position of the tooltips to allow them to line up together as I desire?

Sorry if this is a bit convoluted, I am very tired!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had to use the adjust property! Thanks everyone for at least checking the problem out, sorry if it was lame.